# Why isn't my function get called?

Tags: javascript

Why isn't my function get called? I didn't make any syntax errors.

Also, `return false` isn't the problem. My function should still get called.

```
<form onsubmit='createComment(commentType, currentQuestionID, $("#addCommentAuthor").val(), $("#addCommentEmail").val(), $("#addCommentContent").val(), $("#addCommentDate").val());return false;' method='POST'>

var createComment = function(commentType, questionId, author, email, content, date) {
    console.log('asd')
    $.ajax({
        url: "controller.php",
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            commentType: commentType,
            questionId: questionId,
            add_comment_author: author,
            add_comment_email: email,
            add_comment_content: content,
            add_comment_date: date
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data)
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Is your script actually in `script` tags/external JS file?

Comment: yes sir it is in script tags

Comment: `createComment` defined after the html block with `form`?

Comment: Defined before.

Comment: Any guesses why its not working?

Comment: Is your `createComment()` function declared inside a jQuery document.ready event handler? If so, move it outside of that code block. Better yet - get rid of the outdated `onsubmit` attribute and use unobtrusive JS to attach the events instead

Answer (score 2):

You should change the function name "createComment" as it is global method document.createComment()

Comment: @runucegop then the issue may be in other place, with bpu's solution is working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/yuriy636/ygbp806r/

Comment: Do you have any tips on where?

Comment: It is better to keep your jquery code inside function instead of passing it as function parameters. Not sure from where comes parameters "commentType", "currentQuestionID", but I think it is better to use static text or to use some jquery code for getting it dynamically:
https://jsfiddle.net/c5c9wafc/1/